# How to post on the wall of a person who is not your friend facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

My goal is to post on the wall of several persons (whether or not my friends) from my application in facebook (made in php) after an event has taken place by a button.
The "Facebook User ID" (FBUID) I get them and I have heard that I can post by the graph api if users gives me permission "publish_stream".
I tried to do with the graph api, using "feed" as follows:

```
$ fbuid = array (0 => 'first_fbuid', 1 => 'second_fbuid', ......) / / These are ID's that are and are not my friends.

foreach ($ fbuid as fb) {
$ facebook-> api ("/ $ fb / feed ',' post ', array (
         'message' => some_message,
         'name' => 'My application name',
         'description' => 'description goes here',
         'picture' => $ imageurl));
}
```

But when I try to post to people who are NOT my friends gives me an error. Only does the posting on the wall of people who are my friends.
Is there a way to do otherwise by POST to those people? Or can not by restrictions on facebook? Is there another way?

Note: For comments on the website, it says that my own application without problems can post on the wall of people getting the access_token. Can you do that?

---

UPDATE: If the post to anyone is not possible, so.. Can I send a request to anyone? I think is posible because games like FarmVille do that.
The request can be automatically? Without dialog?
Or if posible to send a Notification to anyone user?.. In the api I see a function called send.Notification.

Comment: I'd imagine that restrictions by Facebook wouldn't make this possible...probably for a good reason, too.

Comment: Reason of Error could be the User Privacy Settings and Application Access you might wanna checkout that thing...!!

Comment: Uuhhmm,I think that games like farmville can do that. They can send notifications to anyone, friend or not.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way.  The API reflects what a normal Facebook user can reasonably do within the terms of the site, and with respect to the other party's privacy wishes.  If you can't post on their wall without being their friend *as a human being*, why would Facebook want to allow someone to do that *through an API*?

I would say that this is impossible to do within the usage rules of the API.

<sup>Not to mention all of the drama Facebook has with privacy issues.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

are you talking about posting on the user wall like this app for example? http://applionaire.me/supporters/

If that's the case, then you don't really need access token to do that.
You would need an access token if you wanted to post on the user wall whether they are logged in to facebook or not.